# How can I fill hinge mortises and latch bores so I can reuse old doors?

Tags: wood, doors

I have several old solid wood doors.  I want to refinish them and use new hinges and doorknobs.  How is the best way to repair existing hinge cutouts and holes and door cutout and holes?  Thank you.  Jean

Comment: Are you staining or painting? Why do you need to fill the mortises and bores?

Answer (score 1):

1/8th" Luaun plywood from the big box store and a good chisel should let you cut out very tight fitting patch pieces with some practice.  That'll get it into paint shape.  For a stain finish, you would have to try to match the grain and color, which would be a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

I have very good results filling lock bores and hinge mortises on doors, and latch holes in jambs, using 2 part wood filler. It's polyester resin filler similar to automobile body filler: bonds tightly, easily shaped with "cheese grater" planes and sandpaper, cures hard, will not shrink, can be drilled/screwed into/chiseled, etc.

Works great as long as you will be painting.